# Does eclipse have a way of finding all JSP pages where a tag uses a deprecated attribute?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, deprecated

We are upgrading our front-end framework from Struts 2.3 to Struts 2.5. One thing that needs to be done is fixing a bunch of deprecated attributes on struts JSTL tags. I have used find and replace for the most part to find nearly all of them, but I want to make sure I got rid of all of them. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find a way to find all usages of deprecated attributes on tags. There is a way to find deprecated java properties, but not to find deprecated JSTL tag attributes.. the fact that JSTL tags don't appear to have a clearly defined way of declaring depreciation doesn't help.

Is there a way find usages of deprecated attributes on JSTL tags across an entire project?

Comment: Unlikely. .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you can find deprecated attributes in `.tld` files or in tldocs generated from them. For example [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library 1.1 Tag Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/).

Usually deprecation is bolded in the `description` tag.

Then knowing which tag's attributes are deprecated you can find them in the project files.